# C++ checking if a part of string is consistent with another part of string

Tags: c++, string

I am creating a program which can decide if user's direction of movement is in a clockwise direction (**N E S W**).

For example I have variables:

```
string correctDirection = "NESW";
string UsersDirection = "WS" //User's direction: west, south
```

UsersDirection isn't in the clockwise direction, because it would has to be "SW", like in correctDirection. I don't know how to compare these two strings, I don't know even how to start.

Comment: Isn't `EN` considered as a clockwise direction?

Comment: Create an set of all the acceptable combinations.  Then you just need to check if the string you have is in the set.  If it is, great, if not, ask for a new direction.

Comment: Is there any limit on UsersDirection and the amount of movement they can make? If it can't be greater than 4, why not just check if UsersDirection is equal to correctDirection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `string` here means [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), you can use [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to check if one string is contained in another string.

```
if (correctDirection.find(UsersDirection) != std::string::npos) {
    // UsersDirection is contained in correctDirection
}
```

Comment: That is excatly what I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can implement a reusable function that supports other languages as well.

```
boolean isClockwise(string correctDirection, string UsersDirection) {
    return correctDirection.find(UsersDirection) != string::npos;
}
```